# get the selected value from dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

i have three different dropdown lists on same values

controller

```
    ViewData["Banks"] = new SelectList(bankslist, "Id", "banks");
    ViewBag.Banks = new SelectList(bankslist, "Id", "banks");
```

the view

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Banks" id="thebankid1"></select>

    @Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewBag.Banks as SelectList, "Select----", new { @id = "thebankid2", @class = "form-control"})
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@(ViewData["Banks"] as SelectList)" id="thebankid3"></select>
```

i load the modal like this may be there is problem here but the list load fine only when i try to get the values

```
function View(e) {
                        var departement_id = e;
                        $.ajax
                            ({
                                //url: '/Location/Getfact',
                                url: '/DashBoard/UserPageView' + "?date=" + e,
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                                    $("#myModal").modal("show");
                                    initializeFlatpickr();
                                    $("#kt_datepicker_11").flatpickr(
                                        {
                                            static: true
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                            });
                    }
```

this is UserPageView action

```
public IActionResult UserPageView(DateTime date)

        {

            var gert = new List<verss>();

            gert.Clear();


            List<SqlParameter> sqlParms = new List<SqlParameter>
            {
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@regie", Value = 22 },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@date ", Value = date },

            };



           var bankslist = _context.Banks.ToList();


            gert = _context.Versses
               .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.gettap2 @regie, @date", sqlParms.ToArray())
               .AsNoTracking()
           .ToList();

            ViewData["Banks"] = new SelectList(bankslist, "Id", "banks");


            ViewBag.Banks = new SelectList(bankslist, "Id", "banks");


            return PartialView("_vers2", gert );

        }
```

html modal

```
    <div class="modal fade " data-bs-backdrop="static" id="myModal" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                       
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="savemodal()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

partial view

```
  <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Banks" id="thebankid1"></select>

    @Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewBag.Banks as SelectList, "Select----", new { @id = "thebankid2", @class = "form-control"})


    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@(ViewData["Banks"] as SelectList)" id="thebankid3"></select>
```

jquery

```
 function savemodal(e) {
      var selectedBankId = $("#thebankid1").val();
      var selectedBankId2 = $("#thebankid2").val();
      var selectedBankId3 = $("#thebankid3").val();

       alert(selectedBankId);
       alert(selectedBankId2);
       alert(selectedBankId3);
}
```

in the #thebankid1 and #thebankid3 i always get record number one no matter the selection is
in #thebankid2 i get blank record

Comment: Could you share more about  function savemodal(e)  ? How you excute this method ?

Comment: from partial view modal

Comment: @Lord_Jury Please, for next time take also an eye on code intentation. This improves the readability.

Comment: Please provide the *rendered* HTML.   [edit] your question and click `[<>]` to add a snippet.   This should include jquery (an option on the left) along with your *rendered* HTML and the js.   If the issue does not occur in the snippet, then it's likely you have multiple elements with the same ID (especially if they're in dialogs) so `$("#thebankid1")` is selecting a *different* element than the one you're expecting.  You could also do `console.log($("[id=thebankid1]").length)` to see if there's more than one.

Comment: i always get value 2 in console.log($("[id=thebankid1]").length)    https://i.ibb.co/7VXR5rB/2023-05-16-092647.png

Comment: Good - that confirms that you have *two* `select` with the same ID.

Comment: i have update the question please take a look –

Answer (score 0):

> in the #thebankid1 and #thebankid3 i always get record number one no
> matter the selection is in #thebankid2 i get blank record

Do you want something like below? Try to add `onClick="savemodal()"`:

```
    <div class="modal fade " data-bs-backdrop="static" id="myModal" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="savemodal()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button"    onclick="View()"> view </button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
      function View() {
       
        $.ajax
            ({
                //url: '/Location/Getfact',
                url: '/DashBoard/UserPageView' ,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                    $("#myModal").modal("show");
                    initializeFlatpickr();
                    $("#kt_datepicker_11").flatpickr(
                        {
                            static: true
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
    }
    function savemodal() {


        var selectedBankId = $("#thebankid1").val();
        var selectedBankId2 = $("#thebankid2").val();
        var selectedBankId3 = $("#thebankid3").val();


        alert(selectedBankId);
        alert(selectedBankId2);
        alert(selectedBankId3);
    }
</script>
```

and the UserPageView :

```
public IActionResult UserPageView()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> bankslist = new()
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Latur" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Solapur" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Nanded" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Nashik" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Nagpur" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "Kolhapur" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "Pune" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "8", Text = "Mumbai" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "9", Text = "Delhi" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "10", Text = "Noida" }
            };
            ViewBag.Banks = new SelectList(bankslist, "Value", "Text");
            return PartialView("_vers2");
        }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @Lord_Jury Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: i have update the question please take a look

Comment: @Lord_Jury I test with your update code, do you want like this?

Comment: thank you for the effort i have update how i load the modal may is there the problem

Comment: i have add UserPageView

Comment: @Lord_Jury  I test your way to  load the modal ,it's  all right, you can refer to it.

Comment: it work in the initial page but do not work on the modal i cant find why

Comment: @Lord_Jury That's strange. My demo is work on the modal . Could you build a small demo and share it via gihub ?

Comment: i have create small demo and working fine only inside my project